# How to create a PowerShell script that connects to multiple services and produce a single output?

Tags: powershell, administrator, exchange, microsoft-teams

I am new to PowerShell and Teams Admin Centre so I appreciate any assistance and feedback that you can provide.

I am trying to create a script that collects Teams data from (1) Get-UnifiedGroup and then additional information from (2) Get-Recipient and (3) Get-Teams. The process of gathering information from (1) and (2) is successful. However, to use MicrosoftTeams modules (in PowerShell) I need the *GroupID*, not *GUID* or *ExchangeGUID* (which Get-UnifiedGroup gets). In order to get the required information, I added (2) to get the *Owners* and (3) to get the *GroupID*. [If you know of a better method, I am happy to listen.]

I use *[UnifiedGroup].Alias* to then lookup information from Get-Teams (Get-Team -MailNickName *[UnifiedGroup].Alias*). [I was using *[UnifiedGroup].Displayname* previously, but [there is a known error that Get-Team cannot accept "&"](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/8093). The "solution" is to convert using "[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode()". However, I could not figure out how to action this solution, so I changed tactic.]

I  managed to put a somewhat successful script together. When I run the script, I successfully get the data from (1) Get-UnifiedGroup and (2) Get-Recipient, but not (3) Get-Teams. If anyone is able to inform me of the error in my code, I would be greatly appreciative.

Below is the whole code (advice on this is welcome).

```
 Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName [my email]
 #Connect-SPOService -Url https://[notcontoso]-admin.sharepoint.com/ [not needed in this script]
 Connect-MicrosoftTeams 
    
 $Date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm"
    
 $exportLocation = "D:\...\2. Reports\Get_AllTeamDetails_$Date.csv"
 $Path=$exportLocation
    
 #Main Command - Properties
 $Properties = 'DisplayName', 'ManagedBy', 'Emailaddresses', 'Notes', 'AccessType', 'IsMembershipDynamic', 'GroupMemberCount', 'GroupExternalMemberCount', 'WhenCreated', 'WhenChanged', 'ExpirationTime', 'Guid', 'Alias', 'SharePointSiteUrl', 'SharePointDocumentsUrl', 'Language', 'ExchangeGuid'
 #Main Command
 $AllGroups = Get-UnifiedGroup -Filter {ResourceProvisioningOptions -eq "Team"} -ResultSize Unlimited | Select $Properties 
    
 $Result = @()
 $i = 1 
 $TotalGroups = $AllGroups.Count
    
 #Secondary Command to get Owners
 Foreach($Group in $AllGroups)
  {
   $MailsOwners = @()
   $TeamsDetails = @()
      
   Foreach($Owner in $Group.ManagedBy)
    {
     Write-Progress -Activity "Processing $($Group.DisplayName)" -Status "$i out of $TotalGroups completed"
     $MailOwner   = $null
     $MailOwner   = Get-Recipient $Owner | select PrimarySMTPAddress
     $MailsOwners += $MailOwner.PrimarySMTPAddress
    }
      
   $MailsOwners = $MailsOwners -join ";"
   ##Write-Host "MailOwners complete"
    
   #Tertiary Command to...
   Foreach($Team in $Group.DisplayName)
    { 
     Write-Progress -Activity "Processing $($Group.DisplayName)" -Status "$i out of $TotalGroups completed"
     $TeamDetail = $null
     $TeamDetail = Get-Team -DisplayName $Team
     $TeamsDetails += $TeamDetail       
    }  
      
   $TeamsDetails = $TeamsDetails -join ";"
   ##Write-Host "TeamDetails complete"
      
   $i++
    
   $Props = $null
   $Props = [ordered]@{
                       GroupDisplayName = $Group.DisplayName
                       MailNickName = $TeamsDetails.MailNickName
                       Description = $TeamsDetails.Description
                       ManagedBy = $Group.ManagedBy
                       GroupOwnersMails = $MailsOwners   
                       Emails = $Group.Emailaddresses
                       Alias = $Group.Alias
                       Notes = $Group.Notes
                       Members = $Group.GroupMemberCount
                       ExternalMembers = $Group.GroupExternalMemberCount
                       GroupID = $TeamsDetails.GroupID
                       InternalID = $TeamsDetails.InternalID
                       GUID = $Group.GUID
                       ExchangeGUID = $Group.ExchangeGUID
                       Created = $Group.WhenCreated
                       Changed = $Group.WhenChanged
                       Expiration = $Group.ExpirationTime
                       SPSiteURL = $Group.SharePointSiteUrl
                       SPDocumentsURL = $Group.SharePointDocumentsUrl
                       AccessType = $Group.AccessType
                       Visibility = $TeamsDetails.Visibility
                       Archived = $TeamsDetails.Archived
                       Language = $Group.Language
                       IsMEMdynamic = $Group.IsMembershipDynamic
                          
                      }
    
   $Outputtmp  =  New-Object PSObject -Property $Props
   $Result    +=  $Outputtmp
  }
    
 $Result | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    
 Write-Host "Report exported to $($Path)"
```